# Ansible inventory хосты и пароли из файла

Tags: ansible

Мне нужно выполнить такое задание:

Есть файл, в котором записаны адреса хостов и пароли через пробел вида:

host1 password1
host2 password2
host3 password3

И так далее. Мне нельзя переписывать этот файл, он должен оставаться именно в таком виде. Логин у всех хостов одинаковый. Нужно чтобы эти данные подгружались в файл инвентаря ansible и далее при исполнении моего playbook подключение по ssh происходило с этими данными. Я не знаю как правильно написать переменные чтобы они принимали значения описанные в этом файле. Помогите мне, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я в подобных случаях просто парсю исходный файл через регулярки и создаю новый инвентарь. И потом скармливаю уже его. Типа `sed 's/ / ansible_password=/'`.